# How to install Pygwr in anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, gwr

I have found [this package](https://github.com/mkordi/pygwr) for geographically weighted regression (GWR) but I do not know how to install it so I can have access to it while working with Jupiter-notebook?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, that package hasn't been designed to be installed—there's no `setup.py` or other metadata, so it can't be installed by `pip`, and it isn't on PyPI or Conda or Conda-Forge.

What they apparently want you to do is to copy the `pygwr` directory into the top level directory of your own program, and distribute<sup>1</sup> and deploy it as part of your program.

---

It's worth noting that this code hasn't been updated since 2013, and doesn't have that many stars, incoming links, etc., so there's a good chance it won't do everything you want it to (it may not even work with current versions of Python or whatever libraries it depends on), and there probably won't be any support for it; anything that needs to be fixed, updated, or extended, you're going to have to figure out how to code works and do it yourself.

---

<sub>1. Notice that it's licensed under GPL. This means that if you're going to distribute your program, and your program isn't also under GPL, you'll need to read up on licensing to see what your responsibilities are. If you have to fork the code to modify it—which you likely will—you probably have to give those modifications away under the same license as the original. Forking the GitHub repo, making that fork rather than the original a submodule of your own repo, and making a pull request for anything you change is probably sufficient, but IANAL.</sub>